# Parsing timestamp in Python with Pandas doesn't return a datetime64

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to parse a csv file into a dataFrame as I need to do some analysis on the timestamps. the csv file is well structured, and I can read it without a problem by using pd.read_csv:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

df = pd.read_csv('trip_data.csv', low_memory=False, parse_dates=['datetime'], infer_datetime_format=True)
```

However, even when giving parse_dates and infer_datetime_format as arguments, I still end up with a dataFrame that doesn't parse the timestamps on my file:

```
df.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 8771828 entries, 0 to 8771827
Data columns (total 3 columns):
UserID                   int64
datetime                 object
amount                   float64
dtypes: float64(1), int64(1), object(1)
memory usage: 1.1+ GB
```

So when I try to get the minimum date, e.g.:

```
print(df['datetime'].min())
```

I get an incorrect answer, as I can see that the minimum timestamp on my df is 2018-01-01 00:08:26 and I get 2018-01-27 04:06:37 as minimum... am I missing anything, or is there any way to cast this to datetime64 in another way?

Here's a peak of my csv file:

```
UserID,datetime,amount
1,2018-01-01 00:21:05,5.8
1,2018-01-01 00:44:55,15.3
1,2018-01-01 00:08:26,8.3
1,2018-01-01 00:20:22,34.8
1,2018-01-01 00:09:18,16.55
1,2018-01-01 00:29:29,5.8
1,2018-01-01 00:38:08,12.35
1,2018-01-01 00:49:29,6.3
```

Comment: your code works for me.  what versions of python and pandas are you using?  you can use `sys.version` and `pd.__version__` to find this out.

Comment: I'm running on google colab. Sys version : '3.6.8 (default, Jan 14 2019, 11:02:34) and pd.__version__: '0.24.2'

Comment: In that case all I can think of is trying it on your local machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert your column to datetime manually

```
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])
```

and then

```
print(df['datetime'].min())
```

Comment: It seems that there was one invalid date that was silently not turning my datetime column into the datetime format, but when I converted manually I got the error. After calling errors='coerce' it fixed the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Without a peek at your data source, it's hard to give advice on how to fix this, but a good place to look might be the documentation on parsing datetime from CSV [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#io-csv-mixed-timezones).

A first step might be to try: (parse_dates=True, infer_datetime_format=True)